# Need Help Understanding Notation With Functions

Tags: functions, notation

Original picture:

[image]

LaTeX approximation:

$$f\color{blue}{\substack{(x)\\x\to\infty}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+x)^3}{\pi}}.$$
What does the notation highlighted in blue mean?

I understand that $x\to\infty$ means that $x$ is approaching infinity, but I do not understand how this could be used in a function.

I should probably confess that I first saw this while watching Spongebob... Even though this is a kids show I still don't see why the creators would make up nonsense mathematics. Here is a picture:
[image]

Comment: I've never seen this before... favorited.

Comment: @Jamie: How confident are you that this is actually the intention? Perhaps someone wrote down an equation $$f(x)=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{(x^2+x)^3}{\pi}}$$ and just made a (semantically separate) reminder to themselves that $x\to\infty$? Perhaps someone was writing $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and made a mistake? Or perhaps (and this seems quite likely to me) someone just wanted to write some fancy math symbols without concern for what it meant?

Comment: $\rm\LaTeX$ supports *everything* :-)

Comment: @MagicMan Thank you, I'm new to Latex and could not figure that one out.

Comment: @goblin You may want to unfavorite now, given that the notation is from spongebob lol.

Comment: Sorry if this was a waste of time. Just really curious if this actually means anything...

Comment: It's from that rocket episode where they go to the moon, right?

Comment: @AndreyKaipov "Sandy's Rocket", yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that
$f(x)$
is a more complicated function,
but that,
as $x \to \infty$,
$f(x)$
behaves like
$\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+x)^3}{\pi}}
$.

That can mean either
$\dfrac{f(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+x)^3}{\pi}}}
\to 1
$
or
$f(x)-\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+x)^3}{\pi}}
\to 0
$.

I do not know what the
"$\pm$" means,
since the term following
is monotonically increasing
and unbounded.

Comment: This is certainly one possible interpretation, but given that it has been revealed that this expression occurs in an episode of Spongebob, it seems perhaps more likely it was chosen for its complicatedness instead of its meaning :)

Comment: Oh. They should consult with the Simpsons' writers, who really know this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is meaningless, or at least it does not have any meaning in standard mathematical notation.  In other words, contrary to your expectation, this is just "nonsense mathematics".